# What is the correct way to record a TTL metric with Micrometer?

Tags: micrometer

What is the correct way to record a TTL metric with Micrometer? For an example, returning a cache entry and recording a metric for how long that entry has been in the cache and/or how long until it expires. Should it be a counter, timer, or gauge?

Answer (score 0):

"How long that entry has been in the cache": `Timer` (start when you add, stop when you remove)

"and/or how long until it expires": `Gauge` (now - added - ttl)
But do you really want to track this for every single entry? :o

If you want to track how much time entries would have left when they got evicted: `Timer` (`.record(timeLeft)`)